# Windows 8 Software Updates keeps failing

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

Built a computer and anytime I try to do a single or all updates for Windows Updates, it fails. I try it again, it fails. I'm starting to give up!

My computer is

```
 Windows 8 Professional, 64bit
 Antec 850 watts PSU
 ASUS Sabertooth Z77
 Intel Core i7-3770k
 Crucial 2x8GB Ballistix Elite
 2 Samsung 840 Pro Series 256GB RAID 1
 4 Western Digital 2TB RAID 10
 ASUS AMD Radeon 7870 V2 Graphics Card
 ASUS Xonar Essence STX Sound Card
```

Latest Bios version for motherboard. I'm able to get the drivers installed. Internet connectivity is fine. Memtest is fine.

I'm back on Windows 7 for now, but even that sometimes gives me problems. Example, install the Asmedia USB 3.0 driver, and hangs the computer. Had to reboot and try again.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the failure.

Comment: I'll go into event viewer and see if I can find anything that links to the issues I'm having.

Comment: So for the Windows 8 update failures, the larger 'cumulative' updates install, then upon reboot, say they failed and rolling back. This is on a clean system. No other update installed prior.

Comment: Also, the drive from Intel for the HD Graphics 4000 does not install. Says my system does not meet the requirements.


After reading reviews, it seems like Microsoft released this OS without talking to Intel and other manufacturers about driver support. Very, very poor.

Answer (score 1):

do a clean boot (disable all 3rd party tools/services) and try to install the updates again. This fixes it. The 3rd party service nlsX86cc (Nalpeiron Licensing Service) is known to causes issues with the update KB2770917.

Comment: I'll try that with that update (KB2770917) but there are two more updates that are over 80MB, and one update that is less than 1MB that fails too. It causes Windows 8 to roll back the updates. I'll try and get the KB numbers.

Comment: I don't see the nisX86cc running on my system.

Comment: Well clean boot. No extra startup services. Downloaded from the download center. It got past the 15% but failed at 30% now.  I don't get how this issue is so widespread (by doing a google search on this KB) that Microsoft has yet to fix this, let alone, admit that its bad and not to install it yet.

Comment: cop the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip it and upload the zip.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Mine was caused by corrupt files as revealed by `sfc /scannow`.